# Equivalent of Scheme's dynamic-wind in Ruby

Tags: ruby, scheme, continuations

Ruby has continuations... does it have a `dynamic-wind` construct like [Scheme](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/cont.html)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This answer is written with Scheme programmers in mind (the OP has asked other Scheme questions here before, so that's a safe bet). If you're here because you're a Ruby programmer with no Scheme background, read the footnote for some context. :-)]

MRI doesn't (see below); and if MRI doesn't, that means there is no portable way to use any such functionality even if another implementation provides it.

I actually inspected the MRI 1.9.1 source code, just to be sure. In any case, here is some code to demonstrate that even the normal unwind protection (`ensure`) doesn't work correctly with continuations on MRI (tested with both 1.8.7 and 1.9.1). (It does work correctly with JRuby (I tested with 1.5), so it goes to show it's an implementation-specific thing. But note that JRuby only provides escape continuations, not general-purpose ones.)

```
callcc do |cc|
  begin
    puts 'Body'
    cc.call
  ensure
    puts 'Ensure'
  end
end
```

(To test with MRI 1.9+, you need to either run with the `-rcontinuation` option, or put `require 'continuation'` at the top of the file.)

---

For readers who don't know what a `dynamic-wind` is, it's a way to specify code to be run when the code being covered is exited (much like `ensure`), *as well as* code to to be run when the covered code is re-entered. (This can happen when you use `call/cc` inside the covered code, and invoke the continuation object after the covered code has been exited.)

Totally contrived example:

```
def dynamic_wind pre, post, &block
  raise 'Replace this with a real implementation, kthx'
end

def redirect_stdout port, &block
  saved = $stdout
  set_port = lambda {$stdout = port}
  reset_port = lambda {$stdout = saved}
  dynamic_wind set_port, reset_port, &block
end

cc = nil
# cheap way to nuke all the output ;-)
File.open '/dev/null' do |null|
  redirect_stdout null do
    callcc {|cc|}
    puts 'This should not be shown'
  end
  puts 'This should be shown'
  cc.call
end
```

So, a properly-functioning `dynamic_wind` implementation would ensure that `$stdout` would be set back to the `/dev/null` stream when the continuation is invoked, so that at all instances where `puts 'This should not be shown'` is run, that text is indeed not shown.